How to make FetchContent dependency built as position independent library?
I'm working on a C++20 library package that unfortunately still has to be built with GCC 11, so no std::format is available. So I use FetchContent to obtain fmt and I use it.
Trick is my package carries libfmt.a a linker dependency and my library is linked with shared library. I enable position independent code for myself, but I can't find a way how to trigger building fmt as position independent dependency.
FetchContent_Declare(
  fmt
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git
  GIT_TAG e69e5f977d458f2650bb346dadf2ad30c5320281 # 10.2.1
)
FetchContent_GetProperties(fmt)

if(NOT fmt_POPULATED)
  message(STATUS "Fetching fmt...")
  FetchContent_Populate(fmt)
  set(FMT_INSTALL ON CACHE INTERNAL "Request installation of the library dependency")
  set_property(TARGET fmt::fmt PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
  add_subdirectory(${fmt_SOURCE_DIR} ${fmt_BINARY_DIR})
endif()

what ends up with (same for fmt if used instead of fmt::fmt):
CMake Error at fetch_dependencies.cmake:33 (set_property):
  set_property could not find TARGET fmt::fmt.  Perhaps it has not yet been
  created.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (include)

what means fmt is buried in some non-obvious way. I tried to Google the solution, but people only talk about building platform independent code via direct invocation of CMake on fmt project, not when it's a dependency of something else.

"what means fmt is buried in some non-obvious way." - The subproject is configured when you call add_subdirectory(${fmt_SOURCE_DIR} ${fmt_BINARY_DIR}). Before that call none of the subproject's targets is created, as error message tells you. Actually, with default settings CMake builds all static libraries with PIC. Have you tried to use plain FecthContent_MakeAvailable?

I was also wondering, why not just use FetchContent_MakeAvailable?

It's a quite common pattern suggested these days, apart outputting the download takes place it allows to set some flags before add_subdirectory(). @Tsyvarev you should promote your comment to answer to get more points - I haven't check if the property makes an effect in my case, but at least that works. Thanks.
